# Kotlin Class.forName fails for Mysql connector/j driver with NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, mysql, gradle, jdbc, kotlin

I've added the my Connector/j 8.0 `mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar` file to my `libs` folder and added an entry in my app module `build.gradle` file.

But I get a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` exception when i try to `Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance()` which is below:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.testmate.hscmate, PID: 10196
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method metafactory(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite; in class Ljava/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory' appears in /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-oj.jar)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.<clinit>(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:58)
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:379)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.<clinit>(NonRegisteringDriver.java:99)
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:379)
        at com.testmate.hscmate.MainActivity$onNavigationItemSelectedListener$1.onNavigationItemSelected(MainActivity.kt:24)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(BottomNavigationView.java:204)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:840)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:991)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationMenuView$1.onClick(BottomNavigationMenuView.java:115)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3400(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27301)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7319)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934)
```

here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.testmate.hscmate"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation files('libs/mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar')
}
```

As far as I can tell, kotlin is finding the .jar, because otherwise it would be a `ClassNotFoundException` but it seems my SDK or JRE is missing this "static method metafactory" or something.

Connector/j 8.0 requires java 1.8.x which I believe I'm running with my compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion. I tried downloading sdkVersion 27 to build the app in a lower version but the app doesn't build.

I have no idea why my driver can't seem to find the things it needs.

Comment: **Update** downgrading to Connector/j 5.1 gets it working, but I still don't know why version 8 won't work.

Comment: You shouldn't use JDBC drivers from Android, and - judging by the error - the MySQL Connector/J 8 driver relies on Java 8 features not present in Android, so it will not even work on Android.

Comment: Is there a better driver I should be using? (I know the proper architecture is to have a web service in between client and DB, but I'm just mucking around at the moment)

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.